# How to use muliple condition using filter in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame with two fields. one of the field name is Tag which contain all words relevant to movies. I use AND condition with filter in dataframe. I want to get Tag which contains these words (humor,funny,hilarious,british,bowling). I try below statement but not worked.

```
val DF =dfAfterDrop.filter($"Tag like '%humor%'"&&
                           $"Tag like '%funny%'"&&
                           $"Tag like '%hilarious%'"&&
                           $"Tag like '%british%'"&&
                           $"Tag like '%bowling%'")
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the expressions in `expr`, not in `$` (which is an alias for `col`, and is not what you want). Also I think you meant to use `OR`, not `AND`, because you want to get the rows which contains any one of the words.

```
val DF = dfAfterDrop.filter(expr("Tag like '%humor%'") ||
                            expr("Tag like '%funny%'") ||
                            expr("Tag like '%hilarious%'") ||
                            expr("Tag like '%british%'") ||
                            expr("Tag like '%bowling%'")
                           )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `contains` method :

```
val words = Seq("humor", "funny", "hilarious", "british", "bowling")

val DF = dfAfterDrop.filter(words.map($"Tag".contains(_)).reduce(_ or _))
```

Comment: thanks but Column appear without any data.

Comment: @Radem can you show an example? Maybe you want `OR` in the condition not `AND`. You can change `.reduce(_ or _)`.